# Which word or phrase describes a hotel room that is a stand-alone little building?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, synonyms

I know about the term "bungalow" to describe some hotel rooms, but if it's not a very tropical place, what's another word that can describe this type of room?

The room is basically a little house… is there a good word for it?

Comment: In the States, they're often called "cabins"; at resorts, especially, it's an option if there's enough land to have detached rooms for privacy and quiet.

Comment: Also, cottages... but that's usually pushing it a bit.

Comment: Yeah, "cabins" or "cottages".

Comment: [chalet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chalet) (British) *A small cabin or house used by holidaymakers, forming a unit within a holiday complex.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where you go, they may be called **"cottages"** or **"bungalows"**. In Hawaii, oceanfront stand-alone logdings are usually referred to as cottages.  In non-tropical places these words can also be used.

> - cottage (noun) "a small detached dwelling unit at an institution, a usually small house for vacation use."
> - bungalow (noun)  "a house having one and a half stories and usually a front porch"
>     [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bungalow)

Answer (score 0):

**Guesthouse**

[Collins American English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/guesthouse?showCookiePolicy=true) gives this definition of guesthouse:

> 1. a small house on the same property as a larger main house, used as for
>      guests
> 2. **a free-standing hotel unit**, often like a cottage, rented to
>      guests
>
> (Also ) guest house

**Guesthouse** as described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guest_house):

> A guest house (also guesthouse) is a kind of lodging. In some parts of
>   the world a guest house is similar to a hostel, bed and breakfast, or
>   inn where in other parts of the world (such as for example the
>   Caribbean), guest houses are a type of inexpensive hotel-like lodging.
>   In still others, it is a private home which has been converted for the
>   exclusive use of guest accommodation. The owner usually lives in an
>   entirely separate area within the property and the guest house may
>   serve as a form of lodging business.

Guesthouse photos and description on [storify.com](https://storify.com/Tom_Dwan/top-benefits-of-a-guesthouse)

[image]

Comment: Would guest house still apply if it's operated by a hotel/resort? My feeling is that guest houses are another option of accommodation type, rather than the building itself. A guest house might operate one or more cabins/bungalows/<word I'm after>, just as a resort could do the same.